# 3 column div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create 3 side by side divs (leftsidebar, center, rightsidebar).

I know you can do this with float:left; however whenever I extend the page to the right, the 3 divs float to the left leaving a large space to the right. Is there a way they can stay centred when I enlarge the page ?

Here's what it looks like when I extend it : http://firstwhistle.esy.es/

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't want to do that, my div's need to be exact pixels.

Comment: @FutProgrammer - But how will you guarantee that the user's browser will  be the exact width that you define? That is why the divs are breaking

Comment: I keep my div's the exact size to fit on a average laptop, I don't want them to extend on an imac for example. In that case the background picture will extend to cover the whole page with the div's remaining centrally.

Comment: So tell me: What should be the behavior on an imac?

Comment: The 3 divs will remain central. Look at my main site, it doesn't have side bars but try and scale it, watch the effect. www.firstwhistle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation below is with respect to the HTML in: http://firstwhistle.esy.es/

Give a wrapper class for your 3 columns.

```
<div class="wrapper" >
    <div id="leftbar"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="rightbar"></div>
</div>
```

And for the wrapper class give the following attributes.

```
.wrapper
 { 
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 1362px; /* sum of 3 column width & border size */
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Based on your code the divs are not aligned in a three column layout: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqagPo